# iterate over GroupBy object in dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Is it possible to iterate over a dask GroupBy object to get access to the underlying dataframes? I tried:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5], 'B':['1','1','a','a','a']})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions = 3)
groups = ddf.groupby('B')
for name, df in groups:
    print(name)
```

However, this results in an error: `KeyError: 'Column not found: 0'`

More generally speaking, what kind of interactions does the dask GroupBy object allow, except from the apply method?

Comment: your code works for me as is

Comment: @StevenG thanks for this feedback. Maybe there is an issue with my setup

Comment: in your code you are iterating through pdf and not ddf, are you trying to iterate through ddf of pdf?

Comment: i want to iterate through ddf ... thanks for pointing that out. I edit my question. Can you iterate through the dask dataframe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could iterate through groups doing this with dask, maybe there is a better way but this works for me.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B':['1','1','a','a','a']})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions = 3)
groups = ddf.groupby('B')

for group in pdf['B'].unique():
    print groups.get_group(group)
```

this would return

```
dd.DataFrame<dataframe-groupby-get_group-e3ebb5d5a6a8001da9bb7653fface4c1, divisions=(0, 2, 4, 4)>
dd.DataFrame<dataframe-groupby-get_group-022502413b236592cf7d54b2dccf10a9, divisions=(0, 2, 4, 4)>
```

Answer (score 5):

Generally iterating over Dask.dataframe objects is not recommended.  It is inefficient.  Instead you might want to try constructing a function and mapping that function over the resulting groups using `groupby.apply`

Comment: Groupby.apply didn't work because of https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1587, so i was looking for a workaround

Comment: It was fixed in [https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/1625](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/1625)

Comment: not always applicable due to "apply func once to each partition-group pair", see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60711871/dask-apply-with-custom-function