# Export dask groups to csv

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, dask

I have a single, large, file. It has 40,955,924 lines and is >13GB. I need to be able to separate this file out into individual files based on a single field, if I were using a `pd.DataFrame` I would use this:

```
for k, v in df.groupby(['id']):
    v.to_csv(k, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
```

However, I get the error `KeyError: 'Column not found: 0'` there is a solution to this specific error on [Iterate over GroupBy object in dask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39731098/3279716), but this requires using pandas to store a copy of the dataframe, which I cannot do. Any help on splitting this file up would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `apply()` for this:

```
def do_to_csv(df):
    df.to_csv(df.name, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
    return df

df.groupby(['id']).apply(do_to_csv, meta=df._meta).size.compute()
```

Note
- the group key is stored in the dataframe `name`
- we return back the dataframe and supply a `meta`; this is not really necessary, but you will need to compute on *something* and it's convenient to know exactly what that thing is
- the final output will be the number of rows written.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, in the end I used `awk '{ out=$4".txt"; print >> out; close(out) }' file.txt` running overnight.