# dask.dataframe.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy ERROR

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have used groupby on 2 columns (the df have about 70 columns all float except the date that is datetime) to get a dask dataframe:

`result_ddf = base_ddf.groupby(["firts_integer_column","second_integer_column"])`

I can not use the result because it is in some strange format:

`dask.dataframe.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy`

how can I use the result as a dask dataframe, because when I just try to `.head()`, or `.compute()` I get erros.

**CODE 1**

```
result_ddf.get_partition(1)
```

**ERROR 1**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   1779         try:
-> 1780             return self[key]
   1781         except KeyError as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1765         # error is raised from pandas
-> 1766         g._meta = g._meta[key]
   1767         return g

~/anaconda3/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1609             )
-> 1610         return super().__getitem__(key)
   1611 

~/anaconda3/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    227             if key not in self.obj:
--> 228                 raise KeyError(f"Column not found: {key}")
    229             return self._gotitem(key, ndim=1)

KeyError: 'Column not found: get_partition'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-279-2c7697a2a4f8> in <module>
----> 1 result_ddf.get_partition(1)

~/anaconda3/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   1780             return self[key]
   1781         except KeyError as e:
-> 1782             raise AttributeError(e) from e
   1783 
   1784     @derived_from(pd.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy)

AttributeError: 'Column not found: get_partition'
```

**CODE 2**

```
result_ddf.head()
```

**ERROR 2**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   1779         try:
-> 1780             return self[key]
   1781         except KeyError as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1765         # error is raised from pandas
-> 1766         g._meta = g._meta[key]
   1767         return g

~/anaconda3/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1609             )
-> 1610         return super().__getitem__(key)
   1611 

~/anaconda3/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    227             if key not in self.obj:
--> 228                 raise KeyError(f"Column not found: {key}")
    229             return self._gotitem(key, ndim=1)

KeyError: 'Column not found: head'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-277-bf3c0aecfa21> in <module>
----> 1 result_ddf.head()

~/anaconda3/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   1780             return self[key]
   1781         except KeyError as e:
-> 1782             raise AttributeError(e) from e
   1783 
   1784     @derived_from(pd.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy)

AttributeError: 'Column not found: head'
```

**Things I have tried**

- this is not an answer it just tells that it is not implemented my question is how to make it work in any possible way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57258160/10270590

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the operation after `.groupby`, e.g. if you are interested in summing some other variable `third_integer_column`, the code would look like this:

```py
result_ddf = base_ddf.groupby(["firts_integer_column","second_integer_column"]).agg({'third_integer_column': 'sum'})
```

After that you can run `result_ddf.head()` to see what the first few results look like.

Answer (score 2):

After applying the groupby function you need to perform an operation on the output of the `groupby` function. The list of operations that can be performed on the output of the `groupby` operation is provided [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#groupby-operations).

If you wish to perform a custom operation on the output of `groupby` then you can use the [`apply` function](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply).

Once this is done then you can use `head()` or `compute()` to see the content of the dataframe